# Sorting in Angular by select from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have data in table: Id, word, score , score_list.

score are 0.4, 0.2, -0.5, 0, -0.3 ....

in score_list i have positive, negative , neutral.

How can i sort data with select by score_list?

This is html

```
<select class="form-control">
<option>all</option>
<option>positive</option>
<option>negative</option>
<option>neutral</option>
</select>

<ul class="list">
    <li ng-class="{positive: item.score > 0, negative: item.score < 0, neutral}" ng-repeat="item in words | orderBy: sort | filter: search ">
     {{item.word}} {{item.score}}
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Is there any fast way to sort it.

in Js i have this:

```
http.get('select.php')
   .success(function(data){
       $scope.words = data;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to sort the numbers? Only HTML or some code in your controller? If you can use controller, then this is pretty straight-forward. Use `ng-click` on your select options like

`<select ng-click='someFn()'> positive<select>`

In your controller, you could store the response data in an array and use `someFn()` to manipulate the data. Like-

Let's assume your data is stored in an array named `var numbers[]`, then

```
$scope.sorted = [];
$scope.someFn = function(){ for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers[i]>0){$scope.sorted.push(numbers[i]);}
}};
```

Comment: I want to sorted them by score_list.

For example: if i click on positive to show only positive score(0.4,0.2....) and for others too.

Comment: Try the above code. For positive, it'd stay greater than zero, for negative, it'd be less than zero.